# How to access a module from a store by having its name as a string?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new in Vuejs and I have a problem.

I need to use a store but I only have its name in string. I know that I can access the method that I wrote (all() ) of the store by writing :
`storeName.all`

but I only have
`this.storeName` as a string and writing `this.storeName.all` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store is basically an abject. We can access object properties in these ways:

```
this.$store.storeName;
```

or if we know store name in string, we can access like this :

```
this.$store["storeName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access in a template

```
<template>

  {{$store.state.<varibale>}}
<template>
```

in the JS

```
this.$store.state
```

Here is the Sandbox link will help you setup and use it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-poitras-sosvs?file=/src/App.vue